# Add axis labels to plot from a pdf

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, include

This question is related to my latest question on how to change the font size in a pdf file, without having to change the whole scale of the figure.

I am now thinking about taking only the Plot and adding labels to the axis. I am not sure if that is possible.

Just like before, I am including my pdf as followed:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{PDFs/Training.pdf} 
    \caption{Training}
\end{figure}
```

The pdf I am trying to include looks like this:
[image]

And I am able to take the axis labels and title with a PDF-Editor tool to look like this:
[image]

Do you think adding axis labels and title would be possible? After scaling the pdf, the labels are getting very small and become unreadable

Comment: Would plotting the graph in `pgfplots` be an option for you? Otherwise, can you adjust the size of your graph with your plotting tool that it fits your purpose?

Comment: Hey @Excelsior, thanks for your comment! I don't have the exact data, only the plot as a pdf, so I am not sure if it's going to work like that? The pdf is only one size.

I was thinking about adding the axis labels and title as surroundings to the pdf file, if that make sense? What would you suggest?

Comment: adding text is trivial, but your numbers will still by quite small.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, you are right. I think, I have to go with this solution, since nothing else would be possible. How can it be done with adding text, if I may ask?

Comment: If the data is free to use without copyrights, I normally use this tool (https://apps.automeris.io/wpd/) to get the points. If you need the data points and it is legal to do so, let me know

Comment: The plot is mine. I plotted this in Matlab myself. It has no copyrights. 
It would be good, if I can extract all the data and plot it in tikz or something right?

Comment: @johnny_1010 If you plotted it, than you should also have the data, right? So the x- y-values ...

Comment: Yes. The tool I am using if called Episode Manager, which only creates plots as pdf or png. It doesn't allow me to save the data in any other way unfortunately

Comment: @johnny_1010 Ok, I am not familar with matlab, but I will get you the point and do the plotting. You can have a look at the result and do some suggestions. Give me a minute ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I mentioned in the comments, if there are no copyrights on the data, you can use some [free tool](https://apps.automeris.io/wpd/) to get the data points of a graph.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{data.txt}
    x   y1  y2
    1   9346.504407 9362.980769
    2   7425.530849 8350.961538
    3   1651.442308 6127.704327
    4   -1379.707532    4257.361779
    5   -10552.78446    1310.196314
    6   -9360.426683    -2444.561298
    7   -2228.365385    -4449.519231
    8   -3004.607372    -5326.722756
    9   -1963.892228    -5447.065304
    10  5269.280849 -2302.834535
    11  9187.44992  1413.411458
    12  3682.942708 2622.846554
    13  12363.03085 5699.569311
    14  16617.9387  9399.188702
    15  1454.427083 8723.657853
    16  14476.11178 9680.438702
    17  14490.38462 11814.90385
    18  16440.00401 12653.94631
    19  15815.00401 12533.75401
    20  15795.623   15391.77684
    21  15776.64263 15574.71955
    22  15790.96554 15891.92708
    23  13786.10777 15451.97316
    24  13783.65385 15045.67308
    25  14017.02724 14673.27724
    26  15798.127   14586.58854
    27  12851.11178 13961.6887
    28  13841.34615 14093.75
    29  13788.61178 14041.01563
    30  13785.93249 13987.85557
    31  13783.55369 13480.66907
    32  10794.52123 13116.63662
    33  13778.92127 13122.67127
    34  13776.66767 13120.41767
    35  13773.91326 13168.14403
    36  13729.59235 13123.82312
    37  13769.03045 13769.03045
    38  13766.77684 13766.77684
    39  14774.01342 13966.32111
    40  13720.07712 13871.51943
    41  13759.64042 13961.5635
    42  13715.06911 13967.47296
    43  13754.88281 13956.80589
    44  13752.37881 13752.37881
    45  13918.14403 13766.70172
    46  10760.96755 13234.52524
    47  10758.33834 12575.64603
    48  13742.73838 12531.19992
    49  13740.48478 12528.94631
    50  10919.47115 12030.04808
    51  13735.60196 12524.0635
    52  13733.09796 13127.32873
    53  11669.42107 12729.51723
    54  13728.21514 12718.59976
    55  13768.02885 13263.22115
    56  13723.45753 13218.64984
    57  12711.58854 13115.4347
    58  13718.57472 13466.17087
    59  13716.32111 13463.91727
    60  13713.94231 13461.53846
    61  15688.60176 13871.29407
    62  13709.0595  14062.42488
    63  11687.32472 13757.03626
    64  13704.17668 13704.17668
    65  13701.79788 13701.79788
    66  13657.35176 13253.50561
\end{filecontents}

\def\height{9cm}
\def\width{16cm}

\begin{document}
    
    \definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{218,89,33}
    \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{83,163,212}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            name=plot,
            height=\height, 
            width=\width, 
            scale only axis=true, 
            xtick pos=left,
            ytick pos=left,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=70,
            ymin=-15000,
            ymax=20000,
            xlabel=Episode Number,
            ylabel=Episode Reward,
            title=\textbf{Episode title}
            ]
            
            \addplot[
            color=myblue,
            mark=o
            ] 
            table[
            x=x,
            y=y1,
            ] 
            {data.txt};
            
            \addplot[
            color=myorange,
            mark=*,
            ] 
            table[
            x=x,
            y=y2,
            ] 
            {data.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can adjust the height and width using `\height` and `\width` according to your needs and include the generated pdf file.

If you need some adjustments for the graph, let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I have one issue though with the pgfplots.

I am getting some error and was trying to avoid using this package. I guess, it's only for the axis right? How could we change the code to be without begin axis

Comment: What is your error? We can also try `tikz` and `plot`, but maybe it is easier to fix your problem with `pgfplots`...

Comment: It's saying "usage of obsolete package!(scrpage2) Package `scrpage2' is obsolete."
I am not sure, what that means. I have tried to fix it, but didn't work before

Comment: Can you run my example in a seperate .tex file and get the pdf?

Comment: scrpage2 is not related to pgfplots. Something else must loading it.

Comment: @johnny_1010 regarding your `scrpage2` issue, you can ask an additional question, but as @Ulrike Fischer pointed out, this has nothing to do with pgfplots.

Comment: Sorry! That wasn't the right error. Here is the error:
Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file 'data.txt' in 'search path=gfplotstable manual for details). {data.txt};
Does this mean I have to save a file named data.txt and save the data there additionally? Edit: I tried that. It didn't work!

Comment: @johnny_1010 I defined the file `data.txt` using `\usepackage{filecontents}`. The data is inside `\begin{filecontents} ... \end{filecontents}`. Have you compiled my example complitely?

Comment: I did like you said: A seperate .tex file with only your code, that didn't work. I guess my packages are somehow damaged from pgfplots. I am avoiding using that

Comment: Sounds strange, since there are only two packages in my example. What tool do you use for compiling the .tex file?

Comment: TexStudio. I am not quite sure how to get to those packages on my PC though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122818/discussion-between-excelsior-and-johnny-1010).